# Powers of diagonalizable matrices-basic question

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a diagonalizable matrix so it there is a matrix $P$ such that $A=P^{-1}DP$

So why if we want to calculate $A^n$ we solve $PD^nP^{-1}$ and not $P^{-1}D^nP$?

Comment: Must be an error in the text (or your interpretation) you use: If $A=P^{-1} D P$ then $A^n=P^{-1} D^n P$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you confusing the notations. Let me summarise the facts:

If $P$ is the change of basis matrix from the canonical basis $\mathcal C$ to the new basis $\mathcal B$ (i.e. the columns of $P$ are the coordinates  in $\mathcal C$ of the vectors in the new basis), if $X,Y$,… are the (old) coordinates of some vectors in  $\mathcal C$, $X',Y'$,… the (new) coordinates of the same vectors in basis  $\mathcal B$,

- $P$ expresses the old coordinates in function of the new coordinates:
  $$ X=PX', \quad Y=PY'.$$
- If $A$ is the matrix of a linear map in the canonical basis, $A'$ its matrix in the new basis, then 
  $$A'= P^{-1}AP\qquad(\text{the $other$ way})$$
  The reason for having the formula the other way comes from the relation: $Y=AX$, hence $PY'=APX'$, whence $Y'=P^{-1}APX'$.

Thus, in a basis of eigenvectors, in which the matrix is diagonal, the relation is $D=P^{-1}AP$, whence $A=PDP^{-1}$, and more generally  $A^n=PD^nP^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes but he said $A=P^{-1}DP$...

Comment: It depends on what you denote $P$. Maybe some Freudian slip ;o)

Answer (score 0):

Hello no you calculate $D^n$ by setting the diagonal entries $(.)^n$; then you multiply with $P$ and $P^{-1}$ in the form $P^{-1}D^n P $ and get $A^n = P^{-1}D^n P$.